# Use of package changes in latex

Tags: changes

Hi i am using the "trackchanges" package. 
It works perfectly for for my institute tempealte  but when i add figure it stops working it stops working any suggestion

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{iisctemp}         %This works trackchanges doesnt work
%\pagestyle{bfheadings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{draftcopy}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage[section] {placeins}
\usepackage[inline]{trackchanges}    %This works iisctemp doesnt work
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{nomencl}
   \usepackage{algorithm}
   \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
  \graphicspath{ {images/} }
    \begin{document}
  \chapter{Introduction}
   random text 
  \begin{figure}
\includegraphics[]{1.eps}
  \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

iisctemp package and track changes can be get through this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwHFi6p7Ry9JcVNRSkFSSnJqamc

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How do you compile? And could you please try with an example image (we do not have your figures)?

Comment: Btw: TeX comments do not use `$$`, but `%` and your image should not be within the code.

Comment: Sorry for "$$" i use "%" its a mistake. I am compiling using  TEX studio and i have added the image in this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwHFi6p7Ry9JcVNRSkFSSnJqamc

Comment: I meant which engine you  use (latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex)?

Comment: Pdflatex is used.

Comment: Any suggestion from anyone

Answer (score 1):

Your `iisctemp.sty` redefines an internal command used by float in a way that it doesn't work if the color package is loaded.

You can try something like this around your style:

```
\makeatletter \let\ori@xfloat\@xfloat\makeatother

\usepackage{iisctemp}         %

\makeatletter \let\@xfloat\ori@xfloat\makeatother

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd\@xfloat{\singlespace}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
```

But it would be better if someone would update the style.

Comment: sorry I must have broken that package in 1994:-)

Comment: Thank you but still its not working

Comment: Worked fine for me on texlive 2017 with your example. I tried. But be aware that your style is from 1991 and written for "For LaTeX version 2.09 ".  It can easily break in other places if you add more code or packages.